# Android O Background Service Limitations

Tags: android

In the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#migration) it is suggested that we use `NotificationManager.startServiceInForeground()` instead of `startService()` when necessary.

But I cannot see any `startServiceInForeground()` method in [`NotificationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).  What am I missing?

Comment: It's not in NotificationManager, but in Activity /  Context (eg. where startService is now)

Comment: You'll have to set compileSdkVersion to 26 and upgrade support libraries to 26.0.0 to see methods introduced in Android O.

Comment: For compatibility use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` in the 26.0.0-beta1 support library

Comment: So is the migration guide just wrong then?

Comment: looks like it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the API level of documentation site to see the new methods

[image: screenshot]

You should use the below method suggested by @RobCo added in the 26.0.0-beta1 support library release

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService()
```

<del>And YES, the migration guide for this is wrong, NotificationManager doesn't have a method called `startForegroundService()` even in API 26.</del>

PS: The migration guide has been corrected, and now it links correctly to the `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` method.

Comment: Yes indeed I was already showing documentation for API 26, but as it turns out the method is not in `NotificationManager` at all but is in `Context`... will use `ContextCompat` instead though.

Answer (score 1):

They haven't changed in the migration guide yet.

You should use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` instead of `NotificationManager.startServiceInForeground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything. Looks like google forgot to update the docs.