# Logic behind Android O Background Service Limitations

Tags: android

The new limitations on running background services is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#back-all).

This new behaviour is apparently to stop apps doing lots of stuff in the background without the user even being aware, which is fair enough.

However, one of the suggested workarounds is to use a scheduled job instead.  But doesn't that also potentially result in the app "doing lots of stuff in the background without the user even being aware"?  The only difference being that Android decides exactly when this stuff is done, rather than the app.

So, what exactly is the point of the new limitations?  Or maybe I've missed something fundamental.

EDIT: This is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501697)... that one is about using `startServiceInForeground()` as an alternative (or about documentation relating to that) whereas this question is about using a scheduled job as an alternative (and whether that defeat the purpose of the new limitations completely). These are completely different alternatives.

Comment: I think now the JobScheduler only starts when System has resources available to start. Instead of allowing every Background Service to run as long as it wants using up resource as much as it wants.

Comment: @Abbas yes but surely once the job has been started, it is then free to use as many resources as it wants for however long it wants, without any visible indication to the user, which is surely what these new restrictions are intended to prevent happening?  Typically if you schedule a job to start now, and all criteria are met, then it will indeed start pretty close to now... effectively not much different to just calling `startService()` as per pre-O behaviour.

Comment: Good points. And the solutions which are provided are too focused an Webtraffic. No solutions, if you have to e.g. work with BLE and do scanning for specific devices in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I see your point.

Seems to me (after reading through the docs) this is the only pro that we get using the new JobScheduler.

However if you look through [Job Scheduler Improvements in O](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#jobscheduler)

> Scheduled jobs now support several new constraints:
>
> **JobInfo.isRequireStorageNotLow()**
>   Job does not run if the device's available storage is low.
>
> **JobInfo.isRequireBatteryNotLow()**
>   Job does not run if the battery level is at or below the criticial threshold; this is the level at which the device shows the Low battery warning system dialog.
>
> **NETWORK_TYPE_METERED**
>   Job requires a metered network connection, like most cellular data plans.

You would notice that for each [JobInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#isRequireStorageNotLow()) you get to specify which constraints need to hold for the job to start.

> Once the job has been started, it is then free to use as many resources as it wants for however long it wants.

That seems to be true, since there is no indication from the docs on what would happen if/when the resources are required again. However you can break down your big task into smaller tasks and then use the [JobScheduler.enque()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#enqueue(android.app.job.JobInfo, android.app.job.JobWorkItem)) method to ensure that the JobScheduler stops before starting next job in queue if the System otherwise requires resources. However this may not be necessary if JobScheduler provides a method or a callback to the Job to pause/stop (doubtful since the docs don't get into it) I've never tried it myself.

---

### Conclusion :

So in conclusion while the new API does not completely restrict the Background Services to run *while* required resources are available, it does however provide a platform for the coder to restrict them to start *only* when above mentioned conditions are met while also restricting min lines of code required. Which should in most cases minimize battery usage and provide a smoother experience to user.